# Trying to self contain pop ups which use the AjaxToolkit ModalPopUpExtender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I have 3 different kinds of ajax popups that need to exist across my site. I was hoping that I could simply create a user control for each one and place the panel and modal popup extender inside each one but this doesn't seem to be working. Has anyone tried this before or do you have a recommendation as to how I can avoid duplicate code for each pop up on different pages? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I figured out my issue with the User Control I believe.

The ModalPopUpExtender requires the TargetID property to be set otherwise an error occurs. Since this is sitting in a UserControl I just created a dummy link button that doesn't do anything and I set the property visible to false.

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBlank" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Panel ID="plContainer" style="display: none;" runat="server">
            Hello?
    </asp:Panel>
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" 
            BehaviorID="test"
            TargetControlID="lnkBlank" 
            PopupControlID="plContainer" />
```

Apparently it doesn't appreciate that and the moment I set the visible property to true it started working. Not sure what the reasoning is for a TargetID since, I would think, most pop ups could be called from multiple links about the page. Perhaps I'm still not entirely clear on how this control is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to write the popups in a asp.net user control (a .ascx page) and include that on the pages you need the popups.  Have a public method in the ascx page that will show the popup, and call it from the parent page when you need to.  If you already have a script manager on the parent page, you can't have a second one in the ascx page, but other then that there shouldn't be anything that would stop this from working.  Hope this helps!

edit: here's what my modal popup extender control looks like...

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender 
    ID="mpeClassroom" 
    BackgroundCssCLass="modalBackground"      
    runat="server"        
    CancelControlID="lbClose"
    OnOkScript="onOk()"
    TargetControlID="Button1" 
    PopupControlID="pnlClassroom">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

in my code behind page, my method just calls mpeClassroom.Show();

Comment: Well I tried that and it's not working. Have you done this before? Did you run into any issues?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with hidden link as TrgetControlID is that; when u set its visibility as false, server doesn't render it as well. PopExtender then cannot find control on the page.

Instead of setting its visibility to false, try to apply a style with display:none. This should work !